# Questioning and thinking about Allah SWT

Tags: islamic-philosophy, muslim-practices, theology

I keep thinking about how and where Allah SWT & our Prophets (peace be upon them) would be living in this universe? I keep imagining different things about what they might be doing, how we are being monitored and how we are judged and many different things.

Is it bad to think so, should I stop thinking these things??

Comment: Excessice questioning is not a good sign. because we have not seen the unseen. and if we want to g and run behind kmowing the unseen,then soon we will be mis-guided from right path. these qestions are coming in your mind by devil, so seek his refuge from Alllah

Comment: Constant remembrance of Allah and his messenger is certainly a good thing. However don't think things that have no relevance and not from islam.

Comment: @asifkhan It depends on what you mean by "different things". If you think they are not appropriate, then it's better to not think about them. However, one cannot always control what comes his/her mind so you shouldn't really make a big deal out of it either. It's just the devil's way of tricking people and making them feel worried that they're doing something wrong...just ignore these thoughts. That being said...what do you mean by "**where** ALLAH SWT"? God is not in any specific location. He is beyond space and time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bismillah!
2 notes, I maybe wrong though.

1. If someone asks you do you exist or not? Do you need any sort of explanation? No!
   You know you do exist...if I speak to you for 3 days and nights that you don't exist... you still won't doubt your existence... Yet in the same way we don't truly know about how we exist...how we were created exactly...somethings we وجدان and whatever that comes after it and make us assured. Yet again we may have questions about how and why...about the details...
2. Since we do have questions and obviously people go in different directions... sometimes for the same issue people choose very similar paths sometimes people choose very opposite paths...which one is right? How can we be sure or at least feel more assured that we are on the right path... that we are on the الصراط المستقیم?

The answer that I know is:

Seek constant guidance from Allah and the Prophet and his family... If not then Satan could/might/will deviate you from the righteous path as he has done to many!... Satan is still out there...then where is Allah's messenger out there to protect us!? Hasn't God always sent his messengers to humans? What for now? How can we protected for these questions or maybe doubts?

I may have gone to speak on a tangent subject, but I think it’s related....

Answer (score 2):

The signs and evidence that god exists are numerous therefore we already know that god exists, these sort of questions may come into any persons mind there are a lot of things that our human mind could not comprehend, my advice would be is this there are questions that we may not have answers to in this life, making assumptions will lead us nowhere as there is no evidence or facts which you can base these assumptions upon may misguide us sometimes so steer away from such thoughts if possible, instead what you can do is review the miracles from that give evidence of gods existence it will make your faith stronger!

Comment: I do get that point, but my answer is directed towards others as well, as sometimes the causes of faith weakening is trying to understand what our minds can't comprehend, this is to help you brother and others who may view this question.